# Sync with custom uploader/downloader

Tags: xamarin, realm

Is there any way to use Sync for syncing with some 3rd party services, rest services etc. via some custom service workers which would download/upload data? Syncing and change detection is not so trivial, I would have use for some tool for it.

**update**
Oh, i see. API Bridging is the option of Professional Edition which is 1500$/month.
Is there some free option?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no such built-in functionality for the Developer Edition. You'll need to implement it manually, for example by keeping a list of objects to sync and whenever an object changes, adding it to that list.